# Lifecycle of Alloy Migrations

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am unable to understand [Alloy Migrations](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations-section-36739597_AlloySyncAdaptersandMigrations-Migrations), specifically,

1) When is the migration run? On App upgrade or on every App launch?

2) When is migration.down() executed? I would assume Alloy executes all up() chronologically from whatever installed app version is to bring to current version. What is the role of down()?

Answer (score 0):

Every time the app opens anew (so not on resume) it will check for migrations that haven't been run yet (which is tracked in a sqlite table).

The `migration.down()` would be run when the user somehow upgrades to on older version. This can't happen on App Store deployments, but it might during tests and adhoc/enterprise deployments.

Comment: I checked the code for SQL Sync Adapter and it seems like migrator would trigger after each model create on `afterModelCreate` event - and not on app opening anew. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's called there because you might create and save a model without using a collection. So every time you create a model we check if there's migrations to do, but it will happen only once.